# Using LINQ, how do I choose items at particular indexes?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

If I have an `IEnumerable<Foo> allFoos` and an `IEnumerable<Int32> bestFooIndexes`, how can I get a new `IEnumerable<Foo> bestFoos` containing the `Foo` entries from `allFoos` at the indexes specified by `bestFooIndexes`?

Comment: Hehe, look how much attention you got ;)

Comment: If allFoos is indexable then why not use IList instead of IEnumerable and avoid the casts/conversions required in the examples below?

Comment: @user373743 Because he wrote that he is using an IEnumerable.

Comment: @user373743: I **do** use a `List<Foo>` under the hood. But if I had narrowed the question to that fact, the below answers and discussions wouldn't have been as interesting. :)

Comment: @Oskar yes my bad I missed the tag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Elisha's answer will certainly work, but it *may* be very inefficient... it depends on what `allFoos` is implemented by. If it's an implementation of `IList<T>`, `ElementAt` will be efficient - but if it's actually the result of (say) a LINQ to Objects query, then the query will be re-run for every index. So it *may* be more efficient to write:

```
var allFoosList = allFoos.ToList();
// Given that we *know* allFoosList is a list, we can just use the indexer
// rather than getting ElementAt to perform the optimization on each iteration
var bestFoos = bestFooIndexes.Select(index => allFoosList[index]);
```

You could to this only when required, of course:

```
IList<Foo> allFoosList = allFoos as IList<Foo> ?? allFoos.ToList();
var bestFoos = bestFooIndexes.Select(index => allFoosList[index]);
```

Comment: You probably mean `bestFooIndexes.Select(index => allFoosList[index]`

Comment: @Henrik: I only used it myself for the first time the other day :)

Comment: It doesn't seem fair that Elisha's wasn't given the accepted answer considering he got there first with same answer.

Comment: @Bear: Elisha's answer was good, but the added sugar in Jon's made it better. I didn't explicitly think of the fact that *... If it's an implementation of IList<T>, ElementAt will be efficient ...* and I also like *as IList<Foo> ?? allFoos.ToList()*.

Comment: @Johann Ok thanks for answering. Just fighting for the underdog ;)Yes Linq optimisations for ICollection and IList are well done in general. Ill stop polluting you post with inane comments now :)

Answer (score 12):

```
var bestFoos = bestFooIndexes.Select(index => allFoos.ElementAt(index));
```

If you're worried about performance and the collections are large engouh:

```
List<Foo> allFoosList = allFoos.ToList();
var bestFoos = bestFooIndexes.Select(index => allFoosList[index]);
```

Comment: @Timwi: I was in the middle of writing exactly that suggestion :)

Answer (score 2):

You could make an extension method like so:

```
public IEnumerable<T> ElementsAt(this IEnumerable<T> list, IEnumerable<int> indexes)
{
     foreach(var index in indexes)
     {
           yield return list.ElementAt(index);
     }

}
```

Then you could go something like this

```
var bestFoos = allFoos.ElementsAt(bestFooIndexes);
```

Comment: Dunno. I like it - it rhymes with what I already use to pick one: `var bestFoo = allFoos.ElementAtOrDefault(bestFooIndex)`

Answer (score 1):

Jon Skeet's / Elisha's answer is the way to go.

Here's a slightly different solution, less efficient in all likelihood:

```
var bestFooIndices = new HashSet<int>(bestFooIndexes);
var bestFoos = allFoos.Where((foo, index) => bestFooIndices.Contains(index));
```

Repeats contained in  `bestFooIndexes` will not produce duplicates in the result. Additionally, elements in the result will be ordered by their enumeration order in `allFoos` rather than by the order in which they are present in `bestFooIndexes`.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution based on join:

```
var bestFoos = from entry in allFoos
                               .Select((a, i) = new {Index = i, Element = a})
           join index in bestFooIndexed on entry.Index equals index
           select entry.Element;
```

Answer (score 0):

var bestFoosFromAllFoos = allFoos.Where((s) => bestFoos.Contains(s));